# Sandbox OR Test Environment for Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instasharp

Good Day,

Please share your input if there is any working Sandbox OR Test Environment for Instagram API where i can test and run my code. I prefer to work with Instashrp library but any other tool will be fine as well. Thanks

Comment: Cant comment so posting. @Shiva that tool throws an error saying my account doesn't have sandbox access. Recent IG permissions updates on their API only allow 10 sandbox users for any particular app so that broke this tool. SORRY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test out all the endpoints over at https://apigee.com/console/instagram

[image: instagram api console apigee]

If an endpoint requires authentication, then select <kbd>oauth 2</kbd> from the dropdown at the top, sign in to your instagram account, enter the parameters (if any) for the endpoint and click the <kbd>send</kbd> button.

You should see the results in the response box.

[image: instagram api sandbox environment apigee 2]